# Function that accepts an Object with "Width"

Tags: c#, function

I want to create function that accepts an object that has definition `Width`

My try;

```
Int32 getWidth(object obj)
{
    return obj.Width;
}
```

This will fail, because `obj` doesn't have definition width.

-- More details --

The usage of the function could be..

// a button
`button1 = System.windows...Button();`

// getting the width of a button.
`int width = getWidth(button1);`

The idea here that it function getWidth should work for object that has `Width` properity such as buttons, lables, checkboxes, ....

Comment: Is Width a user define Property?

Comment: @Hayden No, it's the width of a `System.Windows.Form.. ...` element, such as button or label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out the `object`-class has no `Width`-property. What you're looking for is the `Control`-class:

```
int GetWidth(Control control)
{
    return control.Width;
}
```

Each class that derives form `Control` can now be used with that method:

```
int buttonWidth = GetWidth(button1);
int formWidth = GetWidth(form1);
```

Comment: Dammit! There is always a faster fish

Answer (score 1):

So digging further, I found on the [Button page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width(v=vs.110).aspx)
that `Button` (and many other `Controls`) use the Width property which is inherited from `Control`.

You can simply use:

```
int GetWidth(Control ctrl) {
    return ctrl.Width;
}
```

As all `Controls` inherit from this class.